# Como ficar na mesma página

Tags: formulário-submeter

Em um projeto de 20 páginas em HTML gostaria de colocar um formulário em PHP para captar e-mails em cada uma delas. Qual comando para que, depois do alerta, o internauta fique na mesma página onde se cadastrou – e que não seja a página de Contato (a única em PHP)?

```
    if(EnviarEmail($destino, $email, $assunto, $msg)){
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("'.$nome.', sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!")
        window.location = "../contato.php";
        </script>';
```

Comment: Olá. A sua pergunta não está muito clara. Se vc não quer mudar pra página "contato.php", por que usa `window.location = "../contato.php";`? A "resposta" pra sua pergunta então não seria simplesmente: "basta tirar essa linha"?

Comment: Obrigado, Luiz. Se eu tiro essa linha ele trava no arquivo que "trata dados" (a que verifica se os @s estão corretamente digitados).

Comment: Obrigado pela edição, Luiz!

Comment: Por nada. Mas veja só como vc já está recebendo negativações. A sua pergunta não está nada clara. Por exemplo, ninguém além de vc sabe o que é o "arquivo que trata dados". Procure editar a pergunta pra escrever corretamente o problema, use imagens de captura da tela para ilustrar, etc. Este site não é um fórum, ok? Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e, principalmente, leia [ask].

Comment: Ok, Luiz! Minha primeira vez! Acho melhor colocar o código completo. Segue:

Answer (score 0):

Remove esta linha

```
window.location = "../contato.php";
```

Comment: Obrigado, Xeoon. Foi o que disse ao Luiz. Se eu tiro essa linha, ele retorna (trava, na verdade) no arquivo que "trata dados" (verifica se @ está ok).

Comment: Dependendo de como seus arquivos estão dispostos, você pode adicionar o redirecionamento somente no arquivo que "trata dados", e os demais ficam sem por não utilizarem.  Especifique a estrutura do seu projeto na pergunta, para podermos saber que arquivo é esse, qual o fluxo de informação, e outros métodos de tratar esse código. Também adicione mais código, se possível, pode ser útil.

Comment: Obrigado, Jhonatan. Refiz essa questão mais detalhada aqui: (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135167/formul%C3%A1rio-de-contato-atualiza-na-mesma-p%C3%A1gina)