# Formulário de Contato atualiza na mesma página

Tags: formulário

O objetivo é colocar em todas as 20 páginas do site o mesmo formulário de captação de e-mails (campos: nome, e-mail, cidade e estado) que funcione em todas e, depois do alerta que a mensagem foi enviada, fique na mesma página onde foi usado. Se foi usado na página Quem Somos, depois do alerta, esta página é a que será recarregada. Se o form foi usado em Produtos, é a de produtos.html que é recarregada. E assim em todas as 20.

Arquivo (envia-para-mailing.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['acao']) && $_POST['acao'] == 'enviar'){
require("../funcoes/trata-dados.php");

$nome      = ValidarString($_POST['nome'], "Preencha o campo NOME COMPLETO");
$email     =  ValidarEmail($_POST['email']);
$cidade    = ValidarString($_POST['cidade'], "Preencha o campo CIDADE");
$estado    = ValidarString($_POST['estado'], "Preencha o campo ESTADO");

$msg = "Cadastro para mailing através do <strong>site</strong>:<br /><br /> 
        <strong>> Nome:</strong> $nome <br /><br />
        <strong>> E-mail:</strong> $email <br /><br />
        <strong>> Cidade/Estado:</strong> $cidade/$estado <br /><br />
        <strong>> Enviado em:</strong> ".date("d-M-Y  H:i");

        $destino = "mailing@site.com.br";
        $assunto = "$nome entrou em contato pelo site";

        if(EnviarEmail($destino, $email, $assunto, $msg)){
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("'.$nome.', sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso!")
                    window.location = "???";
                    </script>';

        }else{
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("'.$nome.', sua mensagem ainda não foi enviada!")
                    </script>';
    }
}
```

Existe algum comando para fazer em “window.location” a página recarregar “nela mesma”? Vale ressaltar que se tirar a linha do “window.location”, o site recarrega tentando abrir o arquivo que trata os dados (www.site.com/trata-dados.php) que segue abaixo:

```
function TratarDados($str){
            $str = trim($str);
            $str = strip_tags($str);
            $caracters = array("&", "%");
            $str = str_replace($caracters, "", $str);
            return $str;
    }

    function ValidarString($string, $erro){
            $string = TratarDados($string);
            if(empty($string)){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$erro.'")</script>';
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">history.back()</script>';
                exit;
            }
            return $string;
    }

    function ValidarEmail($email){
            $email = TratarDados($email);
            if(empty($email)){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Preencha o campo E-MAIL")</script>';
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">history.back()</script>';
                exit;
            }
            elseif(substr_count($email, "@") !== 1 || substr_count($email, ".") == 0){
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Preencha com um E-MAIL válido")</script>';
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">history.back()</script>';
                exit;
        }
        return $email;
    }

    function EnviarEmail($destino, $email, $assunto, $msg){
            $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.1\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
            $headers .= "From: $destino\n";
            $headers .= "Return-Path: $destino\n";
            $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\n";
            return mail($destino, $assunto, $msg, $headers);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça um ajax, caso esteja usando jquery, ficara assim:

```
    $.ajax({
        url      : 'URL_QUE_TRATA_DE_ENVIAR_EMAIL',
        type     : 'post',
        data     : {'NOME':$("input[name=nome]").val(),'EMAIL':$("input[name=email]").val(),'CIDADE':$("input[name=cidade]").val(),'ESTADO':$("input[name=estado]").val()},
        dataType : 'json',
        error    : function() {
          alert('Email não foi enviado com sucesso');
        },
        success  : function(data) {
          alert("Email enviado com sucesso !");
        }
    });
```

E na url em PHP, faça a mesma verificação, caso queira retornar algo diferente ou um objeto, retorne em json e use o 'data' da function sucess que armazenara o retorno. Essa é a forma mais correta. Você pode dar um refresh no sucess, para simular um carregamento de pagina.

Comment: Leonardo, estou começando a entender programação! Aí tive a cara de pau de entrar aqui para perguntar sobre o script de form que encontrei na internet e adaptei. Com certeza a sua solução é a melhor, mas tecnicamente eu ainda não sei executá-la! Não sei, por exemplo, se o ajax é para substituir as linhas de comando do alerta no arquivo de cima. Desculpa pelo seu tempo, mas pensei que uma palavrinha mágica em window-location = “???”, resolveria essa questão. Ótimo que tenho muito que aprender! Usarei “contato.php” para recarregar. Obrigado!